# Flutter doctor network recources cant connect to github.com

Tags: flutter, github, man-in-the-middle, flutter-doctor

My flutter doctor returns this error
[!] Network resources
X A cryptographic error occurred while checking "https://github.com/": Handshake error in client
You may be experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, your network may be compromised, or you may have malware
installed on your computer.
Please not that this error comes up when i run the "flutter doctor -v" command.

I didn't find anything on the internet and i tried turning off windows defender, upgrading and using a personal hotspot but the outcome didnt change.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76554743/13755145 try the solutions there and if the solutions don't work, adjust your question to incorporate the tried solutions.

Comment: Sometimes it happen. try with vpn.